# How to resize base view in a XIB to fit contents?

Tags: uiview, autolayout, interface-builder

I'm designing a custom view in Interface Builder with auto layout. It's not a view that represents a "screen", it's just a subview I will drop into another view throughout the app. My custom view has all the constraints set here, but the base view is much too big (I find it easier to work this way when setting up constraints). As a result, the elements are spaced too far apart vertically:

[image]

I can drag the bottom of the base view up to manually resize it, but it's imprecise and I end up using a hardcoded number:

[image]

Is there a way to have this custom view automatically calculate its preferred height so that I don't have to try and size it manually, and do not have to assign it a height constraint when I drop it into other parts of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Here i am using multiplayer in auto layout. Please download demo and check it. I hope its work for you.

[Source code here simple demo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apkd3kbhbll0224/TextView-master.zip?dl=0)
[image]
[image: result]